# Why Zend Lucene doesn't find results but Luke does for the same fuzzy query

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

I am coding search engine using Zend Framework Lucene. I'm trying to make fuzzy query:
"name:sxample~"
When I put it into Luke - it founds 14 results (all with word "sample"). When I use my php code -

```
$query = 'name:sxample~';
        $query = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse($query,'utf-8');

        try {
            $hits = $index->find($query);
        }
        catch (Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception $ex) {
            $hits = array();
        }
```

- the hits array is empty. I guess indexing is ok, while Luke and ZF uses the same files.
I'm using Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8 as my analyzer. Can you tell me what is wrong with my php query or is it maybe ZF bug?

Greetings

Comment: Could it be that you misspelled sample as sxample in your PHP code?

Comment: Misspel was purposeful - I wanted that user can find answer for misspele query f.e. - saample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After research I found what to change - if misspelled letter is in the first 3 letters - then it isn't found. I had to set :

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Fuzzy::setDefaultPrefixLength(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a var_dump of $ex inside the catch-statement to ensure you don't get an exception, thus setting the $hits-variable to an empty array?